# Deleting Specific Files in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I am trying to figure out the code on Visual Basic after I have already extracted all files from a folder that was in a flash drive and put them in a folder on the computer.  How could I have this program delete all the files that have not been modified from a previous date in the folder on the computer?

This is what I have so far:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmExtractionator

    Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

        Dim sourceDirectory As String = "E:\CopierFolderforTestDriveCapstone"
        Dim archiveDirectory As String = "E:\FilesExtracted"

        Try
            Dim txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory)

            If(Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(archiveDirectory )) Then
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(archiveDirectory)
            End If

            For Each currentFile As String In txtFiles
                Dim fileName = currentFile.Substring(sourceDirectory.Length + 1)
                File.Move(currentFile, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, fileName))
            Next
        Catch eT As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(eT.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will delete files that have not been modified since the given date.

```
Private Sub DeleteUnmodifiedFiles(directoryName As String, modificationThreshold As Date)
    Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo(directoryName)
    Dim wasModifiedSinceThreshold As Boolean
    For Each file As FileInfo In folder.GetFiles
        wasModifiedSinceThreshold = (file.LastWriteTime > modificationThreshold)
        If (Not wasModifiedSinceThreshold) Then file.Delete()
    Next
End Sub
```

To delete based on a number of days...

```
Private Sub DeleteUnmodifiedFiles(directoryName As String, modificationThresholdDays As Integer)
    Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo(directoryName)
    Dim thresholdDate As Date
    Dim wasModifiedSinceThreshold As Boolean
    For Each file As FileInfo In folder.GetFiles
        thresholdDate = DateTime.Now().AddDays(-1 * modificationThresholdDays)
        wasModifiedSinceThreshold = (file.LastWriteTime > thresholdDate)
        If (Not wasModifiedSinceThreshold) Then file.Delete()
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You, would you know how would I edit that code to delete all files that were not modfied in the past year?

Comment: I'll append it to my answer.

Comment: Okay I added that at the end of my code, but when I run the program.  It extract all the files to the designated folder, but it does not delete any of the unmodified files.

Comment: Debug it and step through the code. I may have something reversed in my logic, the LastWriteTime may be getting updated when you coy the files, etc...

Comment: Okay, from what I am checking its looks substantial.  Do you know a way that the LastWriteTime would not be gettin updated so that the files only extracted would just be recently modified files.

Comment: and also delete the other files